# Ejecutar comando en dos de powershell

Tags: powershell, línea-de-comandos

Buenas :

Quiero ejecutar un codigo de powershell en "Microsoft DOS" y el resultado de este meterlo en una variable para despues utilizarlo en otro comando, que solo he podido ejecutarlo por DOS, a lo mejor se podria ejecutar por powershell...

En concreto con el comando de powershell:

([datetime]"01/01/2017" - [datetime]::Now)

Este me devuelve la diferencia del dia actual con respecto al que le pongo.

Days              : -345
Hours             : -13
Minutes           : -40
Seconds           : -46
Milliseconds      : -709
Ticks             : -298572467097274
TotalDays         : -345,569985066289
TotalHours        : -8293,67964159094
TotalMinutes      : -497620,778495457
TotalSeconds      : -29857246,7097274
TotalMilliseconds : **-29857246709**,7274

Quiero quedarme con los milisegundos sin decimales para despues pasarselo con una variable por DOS a otro comando. 
También si se puede calcular los milisegundos en DOS entre dos fechas me valdria... o hacerlo todo en powershell...

¿Alguien se le ocurre por donde puedo empezar?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, si es por la gente pff... lo pongo por si a alguien le hace falta algún dia... creamos un script en Powershell

## PASO 1: Declarar variables y darles el valor

$ruta = "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox" #ruta donde se encuentra virtualbox

$nombre_VM= "NOMBREMAQUINAVIRTUAL"   #Nombre de la maquina en virtualbox

$fecha = "01/01/2017"      #Fecha que queremos inicializar la maquinavirtual

$time= ([datetime]$fecha - [datetime]::Now)  #Guardamos en una variable la resta completa

$time = $time.TotalMilliseconds #Guardamos ahora de la variable solo los milisegundos

$time = [string] $time                       #Convertimos a STRING para su manejo

$time= $time.split(".")[0]                   #Nos quedamos con la primera parte del split (.)

## PASO 2: Entramos en la ruta correcta

cd "$ruta"                                   #Entramos en la ruta

## PASO 3: Ejecutamos un comando para para la sincronizacion de la maquina pasando las variables nombre_VM

.\VBoxManage setextradata $nombre_VM "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

## PASO 4: Ejecutamos el segundo comando para poner la fecha y hora que queremos cambiar a la maquina

.\VBoxManage modifyvm $nombre_VM --biossystemtimeoffset $time

## Y después para mayor comodidad crear un bat que ejecute el el script:

@echo off
cd C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\Directorio MaquinaVirtual
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell .\CambiarHora.ps1